# understanding the casing system in magento

Tags: magento

Following the [Magento tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-2-the-magento-config#1) I realised I dont understand casing in magentos XML files. I can't work out when something should start with an uppercase letter, when it should be camel cased and when the string should be all lowercase. for example

```
<config>
<modules>...</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>checkForConfigRequest</method>
                </Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_routers>
    </events>
</global>
```

I understand that after hitting the observers tag magento will look for a file called observer in the model folder of the configviewer folder within the magentotutorial folder and will then look for a class by the name held within the class tag.(Please correct me if im wrong)

What I dont understand is why the tag under observers starts with a capital and the following words are all lowercase and the class tag starts all words with a capital letter

An alternative example would be the codePool and frontName tags that are camelcased

Could someone please explain when and why capitals are and are not used.

Answer (score 0):

`Magentotutorial_configviewer_model_observer` is just a namespace to keep things unique, say if you has multiple classes to fire off one event in one module. It does not have to be any case, the closing and opening elements just have to match, most people just generally use lower case.

For your other questions about camel casing I am not really sure, I think it may have something to do with the config defining a module rather than module config.

Magento has bizarre and inconsistent casing, modules are capitalised but only on the first letter, you can capitalise them all but it can cause real headaches because when you are calling the module you have to use camel case instead.